# Remove space between LinearLayout and child

Tags: java, android

This is my code:

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:background="#ea1a1a"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button

        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Boton 1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:theme="@style/BotonColores"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
    <Button
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Boton 2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:theme="@style/BotonColores"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
    <Button
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Boton 3"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:theme="@style/BotonColores"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the result: [image]

But I want this: [image]

How can I remove this spaces?

This:

```
android:layout-marginTop="-5sp"
android:layout-marginBottom="-5sp"
```

don't work fine for me, I want to keep the button color's

Answer (score 0):

can you try following. please add below lines in your `Button`.

```
android:layout_marginLeft="-5dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="-5dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="-5dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-5dip"
```

your layout should like below.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:background="#ea1a1a"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button

            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Boton 1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-5dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="-5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="-5dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-5dip"
            android:theme="@style/BotonColores"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
        <Button
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Boton 2"
            android:layout_marginTop="-5dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-5dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:theme="@style/BotonColores"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
        <Button
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Boton 3"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-5dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="-5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="-5dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-5dip"
            android:theme="@style/BotonColores"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

see : http://prntscr.com/fokxv1

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:orientation="horizontal"` to your LinearLayout and set `android:layout_width="0dp"` to all Button layouts.
Also change the background of the button to something else as I had put below. Then you'll see the real size of the button. Default android button is actually smaller than it's size.

Your code should look as below:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:background="#ea1a1a"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:background="#00f"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Boton 1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
    <Button
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_width="0"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Boton 2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#00f"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
    <Button
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_width="0"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Boton 3"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#00f"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set background color to button

```
<LinearLayout
    android:background="#ea1a1a"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <Button
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Boton 1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:theme="@style/BotonColores"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="#000000"/>
    <Button
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Boton 2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:theme="@style/BotonColores"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="#000000"/>
    <Button
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Boton 3"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:theme="@style/BotonColores"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="#000000"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work 100%

```
  <LinearLayout

      android:orientation="horizontal" android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="50dp">
      <Button
          android:text="Button" android:background="@color/colorAccent"
          android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="0.33"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />
      <Button
          android:text="Button" android:background="@color/colorAccent" android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
          android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="0.33"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />

      <Button
          android:text="Button" android:background="@color/colorAccent" android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
          android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="0.33"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />
  </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, just replace with below code,it will give as you want

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="#0c3372"
            android:text="Button1"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent">

        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="#0c3372"
            android:text="Button2"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent">

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="#0c3372"
            android:text="Button3"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use weightsum in LinearLayout and give same margin between widgets like below code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:marginRight="2dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="#0c3372"
        android:text="Button1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:marginRight="2dp"
        android:marginLeft="2dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="#0c3372"
        android:text="Button2"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:marginRight="2dp"
        android:marginLeft="2dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="#0c3372"
        android:text="Button3"/>
</LinearLayout>
```